# where can I find the wwan fcc unlock for 8086:7560

Tags: lenovo, wwan

Lenovo ships its P16 gen 2 laptops (certified for Ubuntu linux) with the following wwan card: Intel MBIM [8086:7560]. Modem manager see the wwan modem, but cannot enable it (error message:
** (modem-manager-gui:9178): WARNING **: 10:33:30.084: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Retry: Invalid transition

According to Lenovo instructions (ThinkPad P16 Gen 2 Linux User guide: one should "Go to https://support.lenovo.com and select the entry for your computer. Download the wwan-linux-fcc-
unlock package from the product support page. Make sure to check the README to confirm if any
restrictions for your geography apply, and to get instructions on how to install the application.)

However there is unfortunately no such file available on the lenovo sites. And there is also no comment from Lenovo on this failure to provide the fcc unlock file.

This link also appears to be empty: https://www.lenovo.com/linux/wwan-enablement-on-Linux.pdf

Unless anyone knows where the fcc ulock file for the abovementioned wwan card can be found, the wwan modem in the P16 series is not usable in ubuntu or linux for that matter. Is there any information about this around?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the 8086:7560 unlock I was successfully able to unlock on the ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 7 using the script that is located here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/-/issues/751.

You can store the script as `/etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d/8086:7560` and make sure it is executable (`chmod +x`). You will also need to change the header's shebang from `python` to `python3`.

There are going to be some workarounds needed especially if you use suspend/hibernate, since the modem itself is rather finicky.

One major issue is that once the modem is unpowered on the PCI bus it will not be able to be powered up again, needing to be turned on again. This affects the modem itself and the bus it is attached to.

You will need the following udev rule:

#### `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-modem-suspend.rules`

```
# The modem fails to wake up ever again after suspend
SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x1cf8", ATTR{device}=="0x8653", ATTR{power/control}="on", GOTO="pci_pm_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTR{device}=="0x7560", ATTR{power/control}="on", GOTO="pci_pm_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTR{device}=="0x51b8", ATTR{power/control}="on", GOTO="pci_pm_end"

# Use normal sleeping otherwise
SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
LABEL="pci_pm_end"
```

Then you will need a script that runs at boot to set some initial properties of the device power saving so that the modem or Linux does not suspend the device but keeps it always powered.

#### `/opt/keep-modem-awake.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Enable wakeups
## Bus the modem is on
if grep 'pci:0000:00:1c.0' < /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep disabled
then
        echo "Enabling wakeup for bus owning Modem..." > /dev/kmsg
        echo RP01 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
fi
## Modem
if grep 'pci:0000:08:00.0' < /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep disabled
then
        echo "Enabling wakeup for modem..." > /dev/kmsg
        echo PXSX > /proc/acpi/wakeup
fi

# Disable d3cold for the modem
# It is behind the bridge: 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
# https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-pci/patch/20210329052339.20882-1-kai.heng.feng@canonical.com/
echo "Disabling modem d3cold..." > /dev/kmsg
## The actual modem
echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/d3cold_allowed
## The owning buses
echo 0 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/d3cold_allowed
echo 0 > /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/device:4f/physical_node/d3cold_allowed
echo 0 > /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/device:4f/device:50/physical_node/d3cold_allowed

# Use ACPI to reset the PCI and not just power off and power on the device
echo "Setting modem reset method to ACPI..." > /dev/kmsg
echo acpi > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/reset_method
```

Then for running the script at boot:

#### `/etc/systemd/system/keep-modem-awake.service`

```ini
Description="Keep modem awake for suspend."
After=ModemManager.service NetworkManager.service
Wants=ModemManager.service NetworkManager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/keep-modem-awake.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For later scripts, you will need a script that can find the modem because when the system suspends and resumes, the modem ID will change each time.

#### `/opt/find-modem.sh`

```shell
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure path is set
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

for __i in $(seq 1 10)
do
        __modem="$(/opt/find-modem-sub.sh | head -n 1)"
        if [ -z "$__modem" ]
        then
                sleep 0.5
        else
                break
        fi
done

if [ -z "$__modem" ]
then
        exit 1
fi

echo "$__modem"
exit 0
```

#### `/opt/find-modem-sub.sh`

```shell
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure path is set
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Read in commands
mmcli -L | grep '\/Modem\/' | while read __line
do
        echo "$__line" | sed 's/^.*\/Modem\/\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/'
        exit 0
done

exit 1
```

Then, if you plan to use suspend and hibernate, you will have to setup scripts accordingly for that so that they run before and after that occurs:

#### `/opt/suspend-modem.sh`

```shell
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure path is correct
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Get modem ID
__modem="$(/opt/find-modem.sh)"

if [ "$1" = "0" ]
then
        echo "Telling NM to not use the modem..." > /dev/kmsg
        nmcli c down NetworkName

        # Make sure the connection is deactivated
        echo "Waiting for NM to show disconnected..." > /dev/kmsg
        while nmcli con show --active | grep NetworkName
        do
                sleep 0.5
        done

        # Deactivate the modem before suspend as the connection freezes and never comes back
        echo "Disabling modem..." > /dev/kmsg
        mmcli -m "$__modem" --disable
elif [ "$1" = "1" ]
then
        echo "Disabling modem after resume..." > /dev/kmsg
        mmcli -m "$__modem" --disable

        echo "Entering low power mode after disable..." > /dev/kmsg
        mmcli -m "$__modem" --set-power-state-low

        echo "Performing enabling loops..." > /dev/kmsg
        for __i in $(seq 1 5)
        do
                echo "Loop $__i..." > /dev/kmsg

                echo "Turning on modem and enabling..." 1>&2
                mmcli -m "$__modem" --set-power-state-on
                if mmcli -m "$__modem" --enable
                then
                        echo "Modem was enabled..." > /dev/kmsg
                        break
                else
                        echo "Did not enable modem..." > /dev/kmsg
                        sleep 0.5
                fi
        done

        echo "Telling NM to use the modem now..." > /dev/kmsg
        nmcli c up NetworkName
fi
```

Then accordingly the following systemd, this one for resume:

#### `rfkill-modem-resume.service`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=rfkill modem before sleep
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/suspend-modem.sh 1

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

And this one for suspend:

#### `rfkill-modem-suspend.service`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=rfkill modem before sleep
Before=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/suspend-modem.sh 0

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

With these scripts and otherwise, I have had success in keeping the modem alive after multiple suspend and hibernates.

As an extra, you may also want to adjust the NetworkManager connection so that DNS and route priority are lower (higher values) than your main connection so that it is used as a fallback.